# Get more information about the users in my tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the next endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users to get all users in my azure tenant but it is not showing all information about the users, it doesnt show information as: creation date, last login date, password last change date and others.

How can I get the information required?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arsenio

Comment: Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the answer that helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` api only lists the basic properties. If you need to get the other properties, you need to use $select to get them.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=createdDateTime,displayName
```

[image]

All the available user properties are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot get all this info from the one API call and some of them you cannot get at all. For example, last login info you can get from [auditLogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-auditlog-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint or using select field modification from user API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,createdDateTime
```

All field that you can extract from user API you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#json-representation).

For extracting information about some of users activities you can use [directoryAudit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryaudit?view=graph-rest-1.0) call, but I'm not sure that you can extract last password change from it.